# How to parse an input and assign different values to the split string

Tags: python, string, parsing, python-3.x, split

Im trying to create a roman numeral calculator and am unsure how I would parse a user input into 3 parts the first roman numeral the operator and the second numeral while ignoring any spaces the user might include for example XV + L the "XV" would be held by the left, the "+" would be held under op and the right would hold "L"

Answer (score 0):

Use the indexof function to find instances of any operators you want to check for. Then take every character to the left of that index (using a substring), and assign it to one value. Take the character at the index and store that as the operator. Take everything that is left and store it as your second roman numeral.